# Drag and drop in Recyclerview using itemTouchViewer without affecting the animation

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am implementing onDragDrop method in the adapter class.

```
 public boolean onDragDrop(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    Collections.swap(list, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        notifyItemRangeChanged(fromPosition, list.size());
    } else {
        notifyItemRangeChanged(toPosition, list.size());
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem I am facing is when onDragDrop method is implemented, the animation is not good; there's a trace of elements before being replaced. I understand that for drag and drop, just notifyItemMoved method is enough, and with that, the animation is perfect. The reason I am implementing notifyItemRangeChanged is that after drag and drop, I want the data to get refreshed.

I went through a lot of StackOverflow posts and tried implementing the suggestions, but nothing worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by `there's a trace of elements before being replaced` ? Do you mean that the items inside the range passed to `notifyItemRangeChanged()` flicker, or something else?

Comment: @BenP. Yeah. In both the cases, the toPosition item is flickering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a third argument to your `notifyItemRangeChanged()` calls. It can be literally any object, but I recommend `Boolean.FALSE` since it won't take up any extra memory and because "false" and "don't run an animation I don't want" are sort of related concepts.

```
if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
    notifyItemRangeChanged(fromPosition, list.size(), Boolean.FALSE);
} else {
    notifyItemRangeChanged(toPosition, list.size(), Boolean.FALSE);
}
```

---

The reason this should work has to do with what the whole RecyclerView system does when you notify the adapter that items have changed. Part of that process involves the `DefaultItemAnimator`, which has to decide whether to re-use old ViewHolder instances or not. You *want* this re-using, but you're not getting it.

When you pass a third argument to `notifyItemRangeChanged()`, that third argument is passed around the system as a "payload". `DefaultItemAnimator` is one piece of the system that receives this payload, and it decides whether or not to re-use ViewHolders based on whether or not this payload exists.

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
>         @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
>     return !payloads.isEmpty() || super.canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(viewHolder, payloads);
> }
> ```

In your current code, there's no payload, so ViewHolders don't get re-used. This causes an animation of the "old" ViewHolder fading out and the "new" ViewHolder fading in, which looks an awful lot like a flicker.

When you add the third argument, suddenly there's a payload. Again, it doesn't matter *what* the payload is, just that it exists at all. Now your ViewHolder can be re-used, so there's no fade in/out animation.